# CPUS Quota per Region 24. Is it distributed 8 per zone?

Tags: google-compute-engine

The quota of 24 CPUS per Region is mentioned in the Google Cloud. Is that distributed as 8 per zone in the region?

We are not able to allot more than 8 CPUS for the instances in the same zone and the error says "Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 8.0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is based on the Regions and Zones only. I was able to create more VCPUs in the other Regions and Zones. Free Trial doesn't limit you with the number of VCPUs. We have not such statement even in the google documentation that it will limit you to 8.0 VCPUs for the free trial.

Answer (score 5):

You are hitting the limit because your project is in free trial. After upgrading (see FAQ at [1]) you will have 24 cores per region quota.

Sincerely,

Paolo

Link:
[1] - https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/

Comment: Hi Paolo, Yes what I'm using is a free trial. But in the Quotas page of the console after login also says 24 CPUS per region. So is that a general page for everyone and need to check this only after upgrade.

Comment: Hi Narayanarao, Yes, as reported in FAQ page at [1] : "During free trial, there are some product limitations. Compute Engine is limited to eight concurrent cores at a time."

Answer (score 0):

You are Hitting the limit based on the "family" of CPUs you are trying to use.  You know the family during the creation of your VM. The trial does not matter. In cloud its a bit confusing but Not only do you need quota for the zone, but you also need a quota for the vCPU "family" as well. In a free trial I was able to create a 80-core machine. However, I can provide a fundamental way to go about requesting the increased Quota and the information you will need. First up, see what the error is displaying. [image].

In my case, I got a "Family" error but in the notification it tells me I exceeded the C3 quota.

[image]

In this example I am attempting to create a C3 22-Core machine, but I have a 8 core limit. So go ahead and click the Request Quota
[image].

[image]

Select The quota you want to increase by selecting the check box.

[image]

Click the Edit Quotas in the upper right-hand corner

[image]

Keep in mind that This quota only dictates how many you can create within you region. In my set up I wanted to be able to run at least 3 so I Requested 100.
Once done It take a few minutes but the process is relatively quick. You may not always get what you request and may need to request the same Series("family") of vCPUS in another region and create your additional machines there.